# SW 0x6f50 when trying to install crypto applet

Tags: javacard, sim-card

I am trying to install an applet which uses security classes (`Cipher`, `RandomData` and `MessageDigest`), but always get an `6F50` error when trying to install it. The package is loaded correctly but the applet cannot be instantiated. I am allocating all objects in the 
constructor and the algorithms are supported by the card (at least according to the datasheet). If I comment out all security classes references, the applet loads and installs properly. I've tried allocating `byte[]` and `Object`'s and it works, so this is not a space related problem (64K card with nothing else on it). I am using the SIM Alliance Loader v2 to load the applet. 'Regular' (non-crypto and STK) applets work fine.

The card supports Java Card 2.1.1 and a subset of Global Platform 2.1.1. Specs are here: http://shop.shadytel.com/sim_datasheet.pdf

Any ideas as to what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what the problem is as the card returns a proprietary status word that it normally should not return. The `6Fxx` error codes are used for unknown errors in the ISO/IEC 7816-4 standards. The value `50` is therefore proprietary to the smart card implementation. Contact the vendor.

The datasheet shows us a *very* limited Java Card platform, it only shows support for the following cryptographic algorithms:

- DES and TDEA (triple DES)
- secure and pseudo random
- SHA-1

So if you go outside of these specifications you should expect a status word denoting an error. Normally you would expect `6A80` though, indicating something is wrong within the command data. The fact that you get an error while instantiating the applet shows that the code is accepted, but that instantiating or initializing one of the cryptographic algorithms fails.

If you have a good debugging environment (as good as a must for Java Card development), then you should be able to step through the Java Card `static install` method and applet constructor.

Comment: BTW, I feel honored trying to help you with your *single question* you asked after *1060 answers*.

Comment: Thanks :) I got the cards through a 3rd party, hopefully they can get in touch with the manufacturer or know something. I tried SHA1 or RandomData only and I still get an error. Loading using checksum+encryption with the OTA key works, so at least 3DES seems to be working. I don't know what is considered a good debugging environment, but I probably don't have one....

Comment: This sentence in the data sheet: 'Maximum crypto algorithm classes: 10' looks somewhat suspicious. If 'classes' actually refers to instances, and the internal applets have used all those up, that could be the cause of the error.

Comment: As for the debugging environment, I'm using JCOP, but that relies on the JCOP simulator for debugging, which is a rather different platform than the one you are running. Normally these cards are either debugged by running a debugger on a card, emulator or simulator, all platform specific. Those are normally included with SDK's that are delivered with the card. Without that you could implement each part of the `install()` method/constructor in separate parts of the `process()` method (i.e. different APDU's) and debug the old fashioned way, much like `print` statements.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing something like this: added a test method that catches all conceivable exceptions and maps them to custom SWs. The cause seems to be a `CryptoException` with reason `NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM`, which sort of makes sense, but should work since DES, 3DES and SHA1 are listed as supported. According to the ATR and the RIDs of most of the pre-installed packages, this seems to be some sort of Prism WIB 1.3 Java Card USIM, http://www.net1.com/key-products/hardware-solutions/gsm-products-licensing/

Comment: There are multiple algorithm identifiers for DES regarding padding. Maybe you could try and write a little test app. that tries all of them. It's a bit strange for a chip with such a large list of memory, then again I presume that memory is used for phone contacts rather than application data. And GSM does not use much *regular* cryptography (and the stream cipher it does use is broken).

Comment: I think I've tried all of them, same result. Even `RandomData` doesn't work. I can only assume crypto functionality is not available through Java Card APIs. It seems there is a free AES JC implementation that I should be able to use instead, if it fits on the card. This is mostly for demonstration purposes, so performance is not much of an issue.

Comment: OK, but if you receive a transmission error then the card may not handle time wait extensions particularly well. And if you don't get an answer at all, you may have to wait a couple of hours more... Possibly test with a reduced round version of AES first.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to work OK with 10 rounds on my desktop machine, still haven't tested on mobile. BTW, someone already created a tool that tests all supported algorithms: http://www.fi.muni.cz/~xsvenda/jcsupport.html (same guy that wrote an AES implementation).

Comment: It turns out SHA2 is much, much slower (minutes), because it simulates  `long`'s in persistent memory. Worst part is I have to use it as a poor man's PRNG... It's quite unlikely that I will get any info from the vendor, but accepting this because it's been really helpful.

Comment: SHA-1 would be much faster (not as fast as AES though), and is still relatively secure. Note that it is quite possible to build a secure PRNG from a hash function. Trick is to seed the PRNG while you are without a good source of random entropy. Final note: using cryptography in software on smart cards is almost certainly susceptible to side channel attacks, so beware.

Comment: I thought about SHA1 too, but can't seem to find an open source JC implementation, and don't really have time to port one. Lack of proper seed is a major problem, but makes it that much easier to test :) This is to show off how SIMs can be used as a secure element in Android, if I ever manage to get a proper programmable USIM card, I'll use that instead. I'll open source it when it's done, so everyone can have a laugh :)

Comment: I ended up using AES in CTR mode for PRNG. Here it is: https://github.com/nelenkov/sim-password-manager