# Loading a .cap file onto a Java smart card: LOAD failed SW 6F13

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I am having trouble loading the .cap file onto the Java  card using "gp.exe" . I keep getting LOAD failed SW 6F 13 as an error. this cap file is a base and should be just loaded.Then an inherited cap file will be load and install.

```
>     c:\>gp.exe -load base.cap 
>     pro.javacard.gp.GPException: LOAD failed SW: 6F13
>             at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.check(GlobalPlatform.java:1092)
>             at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.loadCapFile(GlobalPlatform.java:728)
>             at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.loadCapFile(GlobalPlatform.java:686)
>             at pro.javacard.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:427)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18803465/3899583 ...

Comment: @vojta Thanks .But My applet is not contained security classes , as mentioned in [link] ( stackoverflow.com/a/18803465/3899583) . I have LOAD failed SW 6F 13 as an error in Load phase not in install phase.

Comment: Just a bit of background: 6F00 means "No information given", it's something that can be compared with a `RuntimeException` in Java code. So this is probably some error that has not been correctly handled within the Java Card OS / GP implementation on the card. So this is very much Smart Card specific (which is probably why no answers are forthcoming, I certainly don't know).